# Use different bower includes in dev versus production node.js environments?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, bower

I'm trying to set up my first bower/node environment (angular seed). Everything seems really slick and intuitive, except for one part. How can I set up development and production environments? I.e. I want to use bootstrap.css (in my project's DOM) in development, and boostrap.min.css in production. How can I set a corresponding flag of sorts, and how can I implement this idea through bower? I'm not actually writing much node.js code for this. I'm using http-server (npm module) to start and stop a server.

Bonus: Does Bower actually include libraries into the DOM, or is that up to me manually (after I've used Bower to install the client-side deps to my file system)?

Right now, if I do 'npm start' command, it simply fires up 'http-server' node module which listens on a port and serves my app root. I don't actually have any node.js code or anything.

Comment: There is no need to include a min version of one .css file in production if you're concatenating and minifying them all into one file during your build process. However, you could also use some other 3rd party task in your build process to switch from .css to .min.css such as the grunt process task. bower does not have anything to do with this, it's all in your build tasks (grunt/gulp)

Comment: That's a really good point. I am planning on doing that when I build for production. Doh